# Canvas over image

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I have a canvas with transparent background made with FabricJS and I want to merge it over an image that it's already on the page and save the whole thing with toDataURL. I can get both of them toDataURL separate, but I need both in one image.

```
<canvas id="designer-canvas" width="206" height="379" class="lower-canvas" style="position: absolute; width: 207px; height: 379.5px; left: 0px; top: 0px; user-select: none;"></canvas>
<img ng-src="../api/image.php?product=men-s-t-shirt&amp;w=460&amp;h=460&amp;variant=navy&amp;orientation=Front" src="../api/image.php?product=men-s-t-shirt&amp;w=460&amp;h=460&amp;variant=navy&amp;orientation=Front">
```

How can I do that? I tried with drawImage but can't figure it out. I managed to get the image over the canvas, but I need the other way around.

Comment: Can u make snippet /fiddle?

Comment: @Durga I don't think it's possible since I cant reproduce the canvas, since will be empty.

Comment: Put all ur related code

Comment: Why don't you want to set fabric canvas background?